# How to get url from :href in vue and axios?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I try to send post with vue and axios, from :href element, but I don't know how to fill axios url parament from :href.

I try this:

```
            <div id="follow">
                <a :href="'{% url 'follow' recipe.added_by.id %}'" @click="followUser()">Obserwuj</a>
            </div>
```

Href element is fill with Django template tags, and works fine.

My vue and axios code:

```
  methods: {
        followUser() {
            axios.post()
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                })
                
                .catch(errors => {
                    if (errors.response.status == 401){
                        window.location = '/login';
                    }
                });
        }
    },
```

When I click link, error appear: "TypeError: errors.response is undefined"

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like? I would expect `document.querySelector("#follow a").getAttribute("href")` in any framework

Answer (score 0):

You can use destructuration in ES6 to get targeted element, in your case :

```
 <button :href="'{% url 'follow' recipe.added_by.id %}'" @click="followUser">Obserwuj</button>

 ////

 methods: {
        followUser({ target }) {
            const url = target.getAttribute('href')
            axios.post(url) 
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                })
                .catch(errors => {
                    if (errors.response.status == 401){
                        window.location = '/login';
                    }
                });
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send a POST request via URL because the post parameters are not sent via the URL but you can use an alternate solution and instead of using a link to use a button that looks like a link and is in a form: How to make button look like a link? make-button-look-like-a-link.

have a good day, hope you find it helpful.